# change name of view swt eclipse

Tags: eclipse-rcp, rcp

Can anyone tell me how I can change the name of view runtime.

I have two forms. I double click on an entry on one form which opens a new form. I want to change the view name of the second form with value from first form.

while creating the view i set the initial name (required field) in plugin.xml under extension tab and in extension element details. however I dont want this and want to change the name at runtime based on values from first form (as explained above)

I am new to RCP and this is driving me mad (spent almost 2-3 hours but could not find on internet)

Please help, Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to set part name on ViewPart

```
org.eclipse.ui.part.ViewPart

protected void setPartName(String partName)
```